# Transitivity relation in the set of Integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, relations

Prove or disprove that R is transitive, where 
 $R=\{ (a,a^2)| a \in \Bbb Z \}$ is a relation on  $\Bbb Z$

By definition: $R$ is transitive $iff$

$$ (a,b)\in R \wedge (b,c) \in R\implies (a,c) \in R $$

If we pick two numbers $a$ and $b$, such that $ a\neq b$. $a^2$ will never equal $b^2$ (excluding 0 and 1)

So by the definition, we can not find a $c$ such that $a=b=c$.

Because if $b = a^2$ and $c = b^2$ then $c \neq a^2$ by the fact that $a \neq b$

if we let $a$ and $b$ equal the exclusions $1$ and $0$, respectively, once again a value of $c$ that satisfies the definition does not exist.

Therefore, this relation is **not** transitive.

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: Hint: $b = a^2$ and $c = b^2$.  Does this imply that $c = a^2$?

Comment: This is not valid. Say $a=-b=1$ for example. That's not the problem. The problem is that $(2,4)$ and $(4,16)$ are in $R$ but clearly $(2,16)$ is not.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoDris I just edited the question, thanks!

Comment: @AdamHughes so are you implying that I should cover all the corner cases?

Comment: @JLL nope, all you have to do is quote the example I gave to show it's not transitive. Because transitive requires FOR ALL, a counterexample is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition is missing a crucial part. It should be

> $R$ is transitive iff **for all** $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$ it holds that
>   $$ (a,b)\in R \wedge (b,c) \in R\implies (a,c) \in R $$

When you want to prove that a "for all" statement is **false**, it suffices to give a single counterexample.

For example, one counterexample would be $a=3, b=9, c=81$, because then $(3,9)$ and $(9,81)$ are both in $R$, but $(3,81)$ is not.

This, in itself, shows that $R$ is not transitive.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose that $b = a^2$ and $c = b^2$, where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Does this imply that $c = a^2$?

Note that you cannot make the assumption that $a \neq b$.

Comment: How come I can not make that assumption?

Comment: You don't need that assumption.  If $b = a^2$ and $c = b^2$, then $c = b^2 = (a^2)^2 = a^4$, so that in general, $c \neq a^2$, unless $a^2 = a^4$, which gives $a = 0, \pm{1}$.